# (SYCL) local_accessor problem (no template named 'local_accessor')

Tags: sycl

Hi I am so new to c++ and sycl. So please be as specific as possible. Here is the code that I try to compile:

```
/*
    Intel oneAPI DPC++
    dpcpp -Qstd=c++17 /EHsc hellocl.cpp -Qtbb opencl.lib -o d.exe

    Microsoft C++ Compiler
    cl /EHsc /std:c++17 hellocl.cpp opencl.lib  /Fe: m.exe

    clang++ -std=c++17 hellocl.cpp -ltbb -lopencl -o c.exe

    g++ -std=c++17 hellocl.cpp -ltbb -lopencl -o c.exe
*/
/*
    1. How to use Random Number Generator
    2. How to use std::vector as 2-dimensional array
    3. How to suppress warning in clang compiler
    4. How to use Tpf_FormatWidth, Tpf_FormatPrecision macros

    dpcpp naive.cpp tbbmalloc.lib -o d.exe
*/

#if defined(__clang__)
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wpass-failed"
#endif

#define Tpf_FormatWidth 6
#define Tpf_FormatPrecision 4

#include "tpf_linear_algebra.hpp"
#include <cl/sycl.hpp>

namespace chr = tpf::chrono_random;
namespace mtx = tpf::matrix;

tpf::sstream stream;
auto& nl = tpf::nl; // single carriage-return
auto& nL = tpf::nL; // two carriage-return

auto& endl = tpf::endl; // sing carriage-return and flush out to console
auto& endL = tpf::endL; // two carriage-returns and flush out to console

void test_random_number_generator()
{
    using element_t = double;
    using matrix_t = mtx::scalable_fast_matrix_t<element_t>;

    size_t N = 10; // number of rows
    size_t M = N; // number of columns

    matrix_t A{ N, M }; // N x M matrix
    matrix_t B{ N, M };

    // we created a random number generator
    // <int> means we generator integer
    // (-10, 10) means from -10 to 10, inclusive
    auto generator = chr::random_generator<int>(-10, 10);

    chr::random_parallel_fill(A.array(), generator);
    chr::random_parallel_fill(B.array(), generator);

    auto C = A * B; // matrix multiplication

    stream << "A = " << nl << A << endl;
    stream << "B = " << nl << B << endl;
    stream << "A x B = " << nl << C << endL;

}

void test_naive_matrix_multiplication()
{
    size_t N = 10;
    size_t M = N;

    using element_t = double;
    using vectrix_t = std::vector<element_t>;

    vectrix_t A(N * M);
    vectrix_t B(N * M);
    vectrix_t C(N * M);
    vectrix_t D(N * M);

    auto generator = chr::random_generator<int>(-10, 10);

    chr::random_parallel_fill(A, generator);
    chr::random_parallel_fill(B, generator);

    auto out_A = mtx::create_formatter(A, N, M);
    auto out_B = mtx::create_formatter(B, N, M);
    auto out_C = mtx::create_formatter(C, N, M);
    auto out_D = mtx::create_formatter(D, N, M);

    stream << "A = " << nl << out_A() << endl;
    stream << "B = " << nl << out_B() << endl;

    auto idx_A = mtx::create_indexer(A, N, M);
    auto idx_B = mtx::create_indexer(B, N, M);
    auto idx_C = mtx::create_indexer(C, N, M);

    for (int i = 0; i < (int)N; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < (int)M; ++j)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < (int)M; ++k)
                idx_C(i, j) += idx_A(i, k) * idx_B(k, j); // matrix multiplication
        }
    }



    stream << "CPU: A x B = " << nl << out_C() << endl;

    
        sycl::queue queue{ sycl::gpu_selector{} };

        sycl::buffer buf_A{ &A[0], sycl::range{N, M} };
        sycl::buffer buf_B{ &B[0], sycl::range{N, M} };
        sycl::buffer buf_D{ &D[0], sycl::range{N, M} };

        queue.submit([&](sycl::handler& cgh)
            {
                auto a = buf_A.get_access<sycl::access::mode::read>(cgh);
                auto b = buf_B.get_access<sycl::access::mode::read>(cgh);
                auto d = buf_D.get_access<sycl::access::mode::read_write>(cgh);

                constexpr int tile_size = 16;
            local_accessor<int> tileA{tile_size, cgh};

            cgh.parallel_for(
nd_range<2>{{N, N}, {1, tile_size}}, [=](nd_item<2> it) {
// Indices in the global index space:
                int m = it.get_global_id()[0];
                int n = it.get_global_id()[1];
// Index in the local index space:
                int i = it.get_local_id()[1];
                size_t sum = 0;
                for (int kk = 0; kk < 496; kk += tile_size) {
// Load the matrix tile from matrix A, and synchronize
// to ensure all work-items have a consistent view
// of the matrix tile in local memory.
                    tileA[i] = a[m][kk + i];
                    it.barrier();
// Perform computation using the local memory tile, and
// matrix B in global memory.
                    for (int k = 0; k < tile_size; k++)
                        sum += tileA[k] * b[kk + k][n];
                
            
// After computation, synchronize again, to ensure all
// reads from the local memory tile are complete.
                it.barrier();
            }
        
// Write the final result to global memory.
            d[m][n] = sum;
        });
        
    });


       

        // when this block goes off,
        // the destructor of buf_D waits until it is released by the queue
        // and copies to its host memory D
    

    stream << "GPU: A x B = " << nl << out_D() << endl;
}

#if defined(__clang__)
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
#endif 

int main()
{
    // test_random_number_generator();

    test_naive_matrix_multiplication();
}
```

It is a simple matrix multiplication code and I am trying to use ND_kernel for this sycl application. But I am getting errors like these when I try to compile it:

hellocl.cpp(128,13): error: no template named 'local_accessor'
local_accessor tileA{tile_size, cgh};
^
hellocl.cpp(131,1): error: use of undeclared identifier 'nd_range'
nd_range<2>{{N, N}, {1, tile_size}}, [=](nd_item<2> it) {
^
2 errors generated.

ND_range example is from the book "Data Parallel C++" from https://www.khronos.org/developers/books/. from page 225.

Answer (score 0):

The classes that are mentioned in the error log (`local_accessor`, `nd_range`, `nd_item`) are part of SYCL and as such contained in the `sycl::` namespace. You need to prefix those types with `sycl::`, similarly to how you do it with your buffers and the queue. So, write `sycl::local_accessor` instead of just `local_accessor`.

Comment: After I post this issue I did exactly what you said. But this time when I tried to compile I got the error as ;  error: no template named 'local_accessor' in namespace 'sycl'; did you mean 'host_accessor'?
            sycl::local_accessor<int> tileA{tile_size, cgh};
            ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                  host_accessor

Comment: local_accessor is a new type that was introduced in SYCL 2020, and is hence still quite new. I would suggest to check with your SYCL implementation whether it already supports it, and make sure that you are using the latest version. Which SYCL implementation are you using?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am currently using libraries from intel oneapi. I added an environment variable to reach it from VS code. I dont know exactly how to check it. And also how can I check if my sycl implementation supports that?